# PHP xml to html encoding issue

Tags: php, xml, encoding, html-entities

I'm scraping rss feed data from rss xml. Some of the strings have quotes in them. I'm running the strings through htmlentities() before i stick them in the database. Then when i try to display that same information in the browser, the quotes show up as "â??". The character is stored as "& acirc; ??s"(no spaces) in the database

the header of my page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I'm sure other entities are not displaying correctly. How should i go about correcting this?

An example feed with the quotes around "Agawi": 
http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/gaming

Comment: Your database should also use a utf-8 charset, also i think the proper tag is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because those are not regular quotes `“` `”`, more like `Microsoft Word` quotes.
You should take `feedburner`'s example and transform them into `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` manually.

for example

```
$feed = str_replace('“', '&ldquo;', $feed);
$feed = str_replace('”', '&rdquo;', $feed);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP, this routine could be useful.

It adds to the standard get_html_translation_table() the codes of the characters usually M$ Word replaces into typed text.
Otherwise those characters would never be displayed correctly in html output, as your  trouble.

```
function get_html_translation_table_CP1252() {
    $trans = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans[chr(130)] = '&sbquo;';    // Single Low-9 Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(131)] = '&fnof;';    // Latin Small Letter F With Hook
    $trans[chr(132)] = '&bdquo;';    // Double Low-9 Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(133)] = '&hellip;';    // Horizontal Ellipsis
    $trans[chr(134)] = '&dagger;';    // Dagger
    $trans[chr(135)] = '&Dagger;';    // Double Dagger
    $trans[chr(136)] = '&circ;';    // Modifier Letter Circumflex Accent
    $trans[chr(137)] = '&permil;';    // Per Mille Sign
    $trans[chr(138)] = '&Scaron;';    // Latin Capital Letter S With Caron
    $trans[chr(139)] = '&lsaquo;';    // Single Left-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(140)] = '&OElig;    ';    // Latin Capital Ligature OE
    $trans[chr(145)] = '&lsquo;';    // Left Single Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(146)] = '&rsquo;';    // Right Single Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(147)] = '&ldquo;';    // Left Double Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(148)] = '&rdquo;';    // Right Double Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(149)] = '&bull;';    // Bullet
    $trans[chr(150)] = '&ndash;';    // En Dash
    $trans[chr(151)] = '&mdash;';    // Em Dash
    $trans[chr(152)] = '&tilde;';    // Small Tilde
    $trans[chr(153)] = '&trade;';    // Trade Mark Sign
    $trans[chr(154)] = '&scaron;';    // Latin Small Letter S With Caron
    $trans[chr(155)] = '&rsaquo;';    // Single Right-Pointing Angle Quotation Mark
    $trans[chr(156)] = '&oelig;';    // Latin Small Ligature OE
    $trans[chr(159)] = '&Yuml;';    // Latin Capital Letter Y With Diaeresis
    ksort($trans);
    return $trans;
}

$trans = get_html_translation_table_CP1252();
$feed = strtr($feed, $trans);
```